# Order details function in Hybris

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris.
Can anyone please let me know the function to get the order details in Hybris.
I need to pass the order details to SAP via we-service.

Thanks.
Biju

Answer (score 1):

You can use `orderFacade` to get order details based on order code. For example

```
final OrderData orderDetails = orderFacade.getOrderDetailsForCode(orderCode);
```

`orderFacade` is using `CustomerAccountService` to get OrderModel and then populate it to orderData.

Or if you want to get Order History, you can use this function -

```
final SearchPageData<OrderHistoryData> searchPageData = orderFacade.getPagedOrderHistoryForStatuses(pageableData);
```

Comment: These methods, and indeed the entire Facade layer, are designed to be used from a frontend. 

For system integration you should look at platformwebservices.

Comment: @Stretch yes you are right. The best approach is to create custom extension and make it Web Service aware by executing `ant webservice_nature` command. Then We can customize resources and DTOs to send order details as per the requirement. We can leverage OrderFacade and sent the order details in the form of DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris exposes most of the data available in hybris as a RESTful web service

. These files are named as
    `*Resource.Java`.
 you should find something to get order in one of the `OrderResource.Java` files.